# Allow a user to add or withdraw fake money

Tags: php, mysql

For school I have to build a website that allows user to upload and withdraw money. The problem is since this is not a real site for real world use the money has to be fictitious. I don't have a great knowledge of php so I've been looking for tutorials but all tutorials are about real world use and they recommend PayPal or other payment methods.

So my question is does anyone know a good tutorial that can help me with this problem? The website currently allows users to create an account and i have a database for that. So perhaps I could figure a way to tie the money to the users account.

Sorry if this question is stupid. I really don't know much and i need to get this website done soon. So i'm panicking a bit. So if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Create another table in your database that will store info about money balance of an user. So when user is registered you put his account info to one table and his money balance to other table. Then you can operate on second table to withdraw or deposit money per user. You have to link user balance row in money table with user account row in users table. To do that you can use let`s say userId that you assign to each user on registration.

So your tables would look like this:

```
user_table
userId | Name | Surname
   1       X       Y
  22       Z       C

balance_table
balanceId | userId | account_balance
    1          1          22.99
    2         22         -98.00
```

Comment: Okay I'll give this a shot. Thank you very much.